# How does pattern matching work behind the scenes in F#?

Tags: algorithm, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I am completely new to F# (and functional programming in general) but I see pattern matching used everywhere in sample code. I am wondering for example how pattern matching actually works? For example, I imagine it working the same as a for loop in other languages and checking for matches on each item in a collection. This is probably far from correct, how does it actually work behind the scenes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on what kind of pattern matching do you mean - it is quite powerful construct and can be used in all sorts of ways. However, I'll try to explain how pattern matching works on lists. You can write for example these patterns:

```
match l with
| [1; 2; 3] ->  // specific list of 3 elements
| 1::rest ->    // list starting with 1 followed by more elements
| x::xs ->      // non-empty list with element 'x' followed by a list
| [] ->         // empty list (no elements)
```

The F# list is actually a discriminated union containing two cases - `[]` representing an empty list or `x::xs` representing a list with first element `x` followed by some other elements. In C#, this might be represented like this:

```
// Represents any list
abstract class List<T> { }
// Case '[]' representing an empty list
class EmptyList<T> : List<T> { }
// Case 'x::xs' representing list with element followed by other list
class ConsList<T> : List<T> {
  public T Value { get; set; } 
  public List<T> Rest { get; set; }
}
```

The patterns above would be compiled to the following (I'm using pseudo-code to make this simpler):

```
if (l is ConsList) && (l.Value == 1) &&
   (l.Rest is ConsList) && (l.Rest.Value == 2) &&
   (l.Rest.Rest is ConsList) && (l.Rest.Rest.Value == 3) &&
   (l.Rest.Rest.Rest is EmptyList) then
   // specific list of 3 elements
else if (l is ConsList) && (l.Value == 1) then
   var rest = l.Rest;
   // list starting with 1 followed by more elements
else if (l is ConsList) then
   var x = l.Value, xs = l.Rest;
   // non-empty list with element 'x' followed by a list
else if (l is EmptyList) then 
   // empty list (no elements)
```

As you can see, there is no looping involved. When processing lists in F#, you would use recursion to implement looping, but pattern matching is used on individual elements (`ConsList`) that together compose the entire list.

Pattern matching on lists is a specific case of *discriminated union* which is discussed by *sepp2k*. There are other constructs that may appear in pattern matching, but essentially all of them are compiled using some (complicated) `if` statement.

Comment: I believe you have forgotten to make EmptyList<T> and ConsList<T> inherit from the abstract List<T>. Might confuse someone...

Answer (score 27):

> How  does pattern matching actually work?  The same as a `for` loop?

It is about as far from a `for` loop as you could imagine: instead of looping, a pattern match is **compiled to an efficient automaton**.  There are two styles of automaton, which I call the "decision tree" and the "French style."  Each style offers different advantages: the decision tree inspects the *minimum* number of values needed to make a decision, but a naive implementation may require exponential code space in the worst case.  The French style offers a different time-space tradeoff, with good but not optimal guarantees for both.

But the absolutely definitive work on this problem is Luc Maranget's excellent paper [*"Compiling Pattern Matching to Good Decisions Trees*](http://moscova.inria.fr/~maranget/papers/ml05e-maranget.pdf) from the 2008 ML Workshop.  Luc's paper basically shows how to get the best of both worlds.   If you want a treatment that may be slightly more accessible to the amateur, I humbly recommend my own offering [*When Do Match-Compilation Heuristics Matter?*](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pubs/match-abstract.html)

Writing a pattern-match compiler is easy and fun!

Comment: Interesting stuff. I'm proud to pay taxes so that INRIA boffins can work out the best way to compile pattern matching :)

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't loop. If you have a pattern match like this

```
match x with
| Foo a b -> a + b
| Bar c -> c
```

this compiles down to something like this pseudo code:

```
if (x is a Foo)
  let a = (first element of x) in
  let b = (second element of x) in
  a+b
else if (x is a Bar)
  let c = (first element of x) in
  c
```

If Foo and Bar are constructors from an algebraic data type (i.e. a type defined like `type FooBar = Foo int int | Bar int`) the operations `x is a Foo` and `x is a Bar` are simple comparisons. If they are defined by an [active pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx), the operations are defined by that pattern.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile your F# code to an .exe then take a look with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) you can see what the C# "equivalent" of the F# code.

I've used this method to look at F# examples quite a bit.